# In JJ thomson's cathode ray experiment why is the effect of gravity on the electron not considered?

Tags: physical-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, electrons

[image: JJ thomson's setup for the cathode ray tube]

Explaining the setup:

The experiment is described in the picture.
Instead of the magnets in the picture imagine two circular coils on both the sides with current running through it, this creates a magnetic field perpendicular to the loop which can be predicted using Biot-Savart law. Run the current in the loop in such a way so that the magnetic field is going into your screen, away from you. Without the magnets the beam is deflected up towards the positive plate proving the charge on the beam is -ve as +ve and -ve attract.

$q(v \times B) = \textrm{Magnetic force}$

so the magnetic force is acting downwards.
The q/m ratio can be determined as well by combining both the magnets and the charged plates and changing the electric and magnetic fields until there seems to be no deflection on the beam so net force acting on beam must be close to 0 and we solve taking all the forces, more details [here](https://scienceready.com.au/pages/thomsons-discovery-of-the-electron).

I had a problem with how Thomson finds the q/m ratio which is why the gravitational force on the electron is not considered? Only the magnetic force and electric force is considered. I thought maybe gravitational force is negligible? I included gravitational force and got an expression which relates q/m to a constant value

Magnetic force + Gravitational force = Electric force

or

$$qvB +m \times \pu{9.8 m/s^2} = qE$$
$$v = E/B - (\pu{9.8 m/s^2} \times m)/(qB)$$

When we only have the magnetic force acting on the beam, it will always act perpendicular to  the velocity due to the magnetic field going into the screen, so it will constantly change the direction of velocity  but not its magnitude and the beam will move in a circle:

Centripetal force = Magnetic force

or

$$mv^2/r = qvB$$
$$mv/r = qB$$
$$\frac{m(E/B - (\pu{9.8 m/s^2} \times m)/(qB))}{r} = qB $$
$$\frac{mE}{Br} - \frac{\pu{9.8 m/s^2} \times m^2}{Bqr} -qB = 0$$

This can be treated as a quadratic equation where the variable is m. If we have an equation $ax^2 + bx + c = 0$ its roots are $\frac{-b +- \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}$, so that

$$m = \frac{ \left( -E/Br +- \sqrt{ \frac{E^2}{B^2 r^2} - \frac{4 \cdot \pu{9.8 m/s^2}}{r}}\right)Bqr  }{2 \cdot \pu{9.8 m/s^2}}$$

$$\frac{m }{q}= \frac{ \left( -E/Br +- \sqrt{ \frac{E^2}{B^2 r^2} - \frac{4 \cdot \pu{9.8 m/s^2}}{r}}\right)Br  }{2 \cdot \pu{9.8 m/s^2}}$$

But I don't know the magnetic and electric fields. I need the values of electric field of the charged plates and magnetic field of the coils at which there is no net deflection and the radius of the circle the beam goes through when only the magnetic field acts on it, provide the source as well. Maybe there is some other way to understand why gravitational force is not included if so could you explain that way.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149930/discussion-on-question-by-saif-in-jj-thomsons-cathode-ray-experiment-why-is-eff); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: The question should be clear, Why is effects of gravity not included in JJ thomson's finding of q/m ratio of electron where q is its charge and m its mass. What details are missing?

Comment: Pick some electron energy, and find the velocity and then the time spent traversing the experiment. From that time you can directly calculate the distance the electron 'falls' during the experiment. Say 1keV electron and 1 meter. I get a vertical displacement from gravity of ~10 femtometers, but may have made a mistake.

Comment: @JonCuster Yes there is an answer on physicsstackexchange which i linked which has the same answer. That is the best answer I feel as we can also say by just looking at the beam that the deflection is negligible in absence of electric and magnetic fields.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Various versions of Thomson's original article (Philosophical Magazine, 44, 293-316 (1897)) can be accessed freely online, for instance at Google books, or [here](https://web.lemoyne.edu/%7Egiunta/thomson1897.html) (link liable to rot).

But you can work around not knowing the details of the experiment. Interestingly, you don't even need to know the magnitude of the magnetic field applied (therefore current).

Starting from your two equations we can  compute $q/m$ (solving a quadratic equation in *q* instead of *m*):

$$\frac{q}{m} = \frac{E}{2B^2r}+\left[\frac{E^2}{4B^4r^2}-\frac{g}{B^2r} \right]^{1/2} \\ = \frac{E}{2B^2r}\left(1+\left[1-\frac{4gB^2r}{E^2} \right]^{1/2}\right) \tag{1}$$

We can use the fact that
if we assume g is negligibly small then we know the solution is

$$\frac{q}{m} = \left(\frac{E}{B^2 r}\right)_{g=0}$$

Based on this, if we define

$$\left(\frac{q}{m}\right)_{\textrm{approx}} = \frac{E}{B^2 r}$$

we can use a Taylor expansion assuming the gravitational effect to be very small relative to the electromagnetic ones to recast Eq (1) as

$$\frac{q}{m} \approx \left(\frac{q}{m}\right)_{\textrm{approx}}\left[1-\frac{g}{E}\left(\frac{m}{q} \right)_{\textrm{approx}} \right] \\  \approx \left(\frac{q}{m}\right)_{\textrm{approx}} \left[1-\frac{mg}{qE} \right]$$

This result suggests using known constants to evaluate

$$E >> \frac{mg}{q} = \pu{5.57e-11 V/m}$$

as a condition for the value of the applied electric field above which g can be neglected. Using reasonable values for the distance between the electrodes we see that the applied potential required to satisfy the condition is bound to be quite small, much smaller than the range for instance reported in examples online, which are in the order of hundreds of volts.

Comment: If you insist on wanting to know the current applied, work backward using the balance condition to solve for the applied magnetic field, knowing the range of electric fields that may have been used.

Comment: Can you explain how you got $\frac{q}{m} \approx \frac12\left(\frac{q}{m}\right)_{\textrm{approx}}\left[2+\frac{mg}{qE} \right]$

Comment: I made a mistake in the centripetal force = magnetic force equation, I didn't include effects of gravity there Im trying to include it. If I can then there should be a change in the equations

Comment: @Saif Perform a Taylor expansion on $(1+x)^{1/2}$. // Yes, I thought about the additional term in centripetal force balance, but that leads to messy equations I believe. Consider my answer a first-order approximation. Also, consider Ian Bush's comment. This is a different way to justify ignoring the g term.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Taylor expansion so I tried learning it.
$$\frac{q}{m} = \frac{E}{2B^2r} +(\frac{E^2}{4B^4r^2}(1 - \frac{4B^2rg}{E^2}) )^{1/2} $$
$$ \frac{E}{2B^2r} +  \frac{E^2}{2B^2r}(1 + x)^1/2 $$
$$ \frac{E}{2B^2r}+ \frac{E^2}{2B^2r}(1 + \frac{1}{2}x)$$ Here you are using the approximation around x = 0?
so then I substituted for x I was typing this as you edited it, and got what you got in the new edit

Comment: It should be $\frac{E}{2B^2 r} (1 + x)^{1/2}$

Comment: Yes, a few errors crept in but it's correct now I believe. It seems the approach used by Thomson to determine e/m differs from that described by the equations in your post. His approach used magnetic deflection and measurements of heat generated and total charge of the cathode rays. Either way, Thomson's article provides you with estimates of the magnitude of electric fields used to deflect the cathode rays during the determination of the conductivity in the evacuated tubes.

Comment: Really how with heat, I'll look at the article. Anyway Ian's answer is good as it can be confirmed gravity's effects is negligible by just looking at the beam when there aren't any electric or magnetic fields and seeing the beam is not deflected at all + this answer  is good as well. Though I still want to know how and what would happen if I could somehow include gravity's effects in the centripetal force but ill try it on my own.

Comment: I linked here from [my answer to the HSM SE cross-posted version](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/a/15971/3869)